# How to Take Screenshot when TestNG Assert fails?

Tags: selenium

```
String Actualvalue= d.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"wrapper\"]/main/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")).getText();
          
          Assert.assertEquals(Actualvalue, "jumlga"); 
          captureScreen(d, "Fail");
```

Answer (score 1):

The assert should not be put before your capture screen. Because it will immediately shutdown the test process so your code

```
captureScreen(d, "Fail");
```

will be not reachable

This is how i usually do:

```
boolean result = false;
try {
   // do stuff here
   result = true;
} catch(Exception_class_Name ex) {
   // code to handle error and capture screen shot
   
   captureScreen(d, "Fail");
}
# then using assert
Assert.assertEquals(result, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.**
A good solution will be is to use a report framework like `allure-reports`.
Read here:[allure-reports](https://www.swtestacademy.com/allure-testng/)

**2.**
We don't our tests to be ugly by adding `try catch` in every test so we will use `Listeners` which are using an annotations system to "Listen" to our tests and act accordingly.

**Example:**

```
public class listeners extends commonOps implements ITestListener {
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        System.out.println("------------------ Starting Test: " + iTestResult.getName() + " Failed ------------------");
        if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase("web"))
        saveScreenshot();
    }
}
```

Please note I only used the relevant method to your question and I suggest you read here:
[TestNG Listeners](https://www.guru99.com/listeners-selenium-webdriver.html)

Now we will want to take a `screenshot` built in method by `allure-reports` every time a test fails so will add this method inside our `listeners class`

**Example:**

```
@Attachment(value = "Page Screen-Shot", type = "image/png")
public byte[] saveScreenshot(){
    return ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
}
```

**Test example**

```
@Listeners(listeners.class)
public class myTest extends commonOps {

    @Test(description = "Test01: Add numbers and verify")
    @Description("Test Description: Using Allure reports annotations")
    public void test01_myFirstTest(){
        Assert.assertEquals(result, true)  
    }
}
```

Note we're using at the beginning of the class an annotation of `@Listeners(listeners.class)` which allows our listeners to listen to our test, please mind the `(listeners.class)` can be any class you named your listeners.

The `@Description` is related to `allure-reports` and as the code snip suggests you can add additional info about the test.

Finally, our `Assert.assertEquals(result, true)` will take a screen shot in case the assertion fails because we enabled our `Listener.class` to it.